# How to redirect from the login action if the session for a user role is all ready set in symfony 2

Tags: php, security, symfony

I am developing an web application in symfony2. I have implemented login and logout using the symfony2 core security.

I have used userinterface for authentication/authorization.

Now I want to check a condition in the login action, if user is all ready loged in then redirect to the user dashboard.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the ways to do it:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dashboard'));
    }
}
```

Comment: The other way it to set the session on login success. The session key to set is `__security.[firewall key].target_path` where `[firewall key]` is the key you are using in your firewall. For instance `$this->session->set('_security.main.target_path', '/admin');`